# First Pontrjagin class and generator of $\pi_3(\mathrm{SO}(d))$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, characteristic-classes

It is well-known that $H^4(B\mathrm{SO}(d), \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, with a canonical generator given by $p_1$, the first universal Pontrjagin class.
Let's assume $d\geq 5$ so that everything is stable.
We have the following diagram of group homomorphisms:
$$H^4(B\mathrm{SO}(d), \mathbb{Z}) \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mathrm{Hom}(\pi_4(B\mathrm{SO}(d)), \mathbb{Z}) \stackrel{\beta}{\longleftarrow} \mathrm{Hom}(\pi_3(\mathrm{SO}(d)), \mathbb{Z})$$
The left map is the usual map coming from the universal coefficient theorem and the Hurewicz homomorphism $\pi_4(B\mathrm{SO}(d) \to H_4(B\mathrm{SO}(d))$.
The right map is induced by the connecting homomorphism for the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for the classifying space fibration $\mathrm{SO}(d) \to E\mathrm{SO}(d) \to B\mathrm{SO}(d)$.

Now, there exists a generator $x$ of $\pi_3(\mathrm{SO}(d))$ such that the homomorphism $\varphi_x$ such that $\varphi_x(x) = 1$ satisfies $\alpha(p_1) = \beta(\varphi_x)$.

**Q: What is an explicit description of this generator?**

In particular, how does $x$ compare to the canonical map $y: \mathrm{SU}(2) \to \mathrm{SO}(4) \to \mathrm{SO}(d)$ for $d \geq 5$ (which, I think, is twice a generator)? Is $y = 2x$ or $y=-2x$? (Edit: As pointed out by Achim Krause, one has to fix an isomorphism $S^3 \cong \mathrm{SU}(2)$ to make this really well-defined).

Pontrjagin classes are commonly defined through Chern classes, which in turn are determined by their values on complex projective spaces.
My problem is that it seems quite involved to figure out what this really means in this concrete situation.
So what is an efficient way to determine the sign ambiguity?

Comment: Do you mean $(2)$ and not $(3)$ in the second part of the question?  and what exactly canonical map into $SO(d)$ do you mean? the one coming from the inclusions $SU(2)\to SO(4)\to SO(d)$?

Comment: Note that to pin down a well-defined sign, you'll also have to specify an isomorphism $S^3\cong SU(2)$.

Comment: The inclusions $Spin(3) = SU(2) = Sp(1) \stackrel{\Delta}{\to} Sp(1)\times Sp(1) = Spin(4) \to Sp(2) = Spin(5)$ map the generator of $\pi_3(Spin(3))$ to twice the generator of $\pi_3(Spin(5))$. As far as $SO$ goes, the composite $Spin(3) \to SO(3) \to SO(5)$ will still be twice a generator (and it should be +2, not -2). I suspect the generator of $\pi_3(Sp(2))$ is given by the inclusion of $Sp(1)$ as the top-left corner, and if so, the generator of $\pi_3(SO(5))$ should be $Sp(1)\to Sp(2) \to SO(5)$. Then things are stable from then on in, so compose with $SO(5)\to SO(k)$.

Comment: To get the sign right, I think you need to compare (co)roots in the induced map on Lie algebras, or, perhaps better, consider the ratio of the Killing form on $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ to the restriction of the Killing form from $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ using the map in my previous comment, since the Killing form represents the generator in $H^4$ of the classifying space, no?

Comment: @DavidRoberts  the upper left corner inclusion $Sp(1)\to Sp(2)$ is indeed an isomorphism on $\pi_3$. this immediately follows from the long exact homotopy sequence of the bundle $Sp(1)\to Sp(2)\to S^7$.

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch ah, of course, thanks! :-)

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch: Yes and yes. Thanks for pointing this out. I edited the post

Comment: @AchimKrause: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig David Roberts answered most of your question but let me just add that I think under the standard conventions you should get $y=-2x$ because of the universal formulas relating Chern and Pontryagin classes. For a rank 2 complex bundle you have $p_1=c_1^2-2c_2$. The the universal (Hopf) bundle over $BSU(2)$ you have $c_1=0$ and $c_2=x$ (or more prcisely the image of $x$). I am too lazy to check what the second $SU(2)$ in $SO(4)$ gives. It might flip the sign.

Comment: I am a bit skeptical about your assertion right before the main question, as it seems to imply that there exists a vector bundle over $S^4$ with $p_1 = 1$, which seems to contradict Thm. 3.8 in Levine's lecture notes on groups of homotopy spheres. Why should the Hurewicz homomorphism be an isomorphism in degree $4$?

Comment: @JensReinhold: Rethinking, this is probably not true, and I removed this claim from the original post. However, we still get a map, and for the question it is only necessary that the second map is an isomorphism.

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch yes, this needs a careful check. There's the map $SU(2)\to SO(4)$ coming from forgetting the complex structure, but what does this look like in $\pi_3(SO(4)$ in the basis consisting of the two maps arising from $SU(2)\times SU(2)\simeq Spin(4)\twoheadrightarrow SO(4)$?

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig I'm thinking that there might be a Lie-theoretic approach to this, as well (hinted at by my suggestion about Killing forms, but taking it further that what I'm familiar with)

Comment: @DavidRoberts there is indeed a Lie theoretic approach to this. say you have a simple Lie subgroup H in a simple group $G$. scale the Killing forms so that the longest root has length $\sqrt 2$.  then look at the coefficient you get when you restrict the forms as you wrote. that's called the Dynkin index. It's always an integer and is equal to the coefficient of the map on $\pi_3$.  there is a general recipe to compute it but in specific examples it's usually easier to compute by hand.

Comment: @DavidRoberts  about the two $SU(2)$'s in $SO(4)$. They correspond to two different complex structures on $\mathbb R^4$. If you think of $\mathbb R^4$ as quaternions and $S^3$ as $Sp(1)$ then there is ineffective $S^3\times S^3$ action on $\mathbb R^4$ given by $q_1vq_2^{-1}$. The kernel is $\mathbb Z_2=\{\pm (1,1)\}$ and you get $SO(4)=(S^3\times S^3)/\mathbb Z_2$. The first $S^3$ commutes with multiplication by $i$ on the right and the second with multiplication by $i$ on the left.

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch re Dynkin index, yes, that's what I meant when I mentioned "the ratio of the Killing form", above. And I know about the two maps from $SU(2)$ to $SO(4)$ via the isomorphism with $Spin(4)$. The question is: what is the homotopy class of the (pointed) map given by the forgetful homomorphism $SU(2)\to SO(4)$ coming from the defining representation on $\mathbb{C}^2\simeq \mathbb{R}^4$? Is there a way to see how this complex structure relates to the two you mentioned?

Comment: @DavidRoberts certainly. These complex structures are explicit. just take a quaternion $a+bi+cj+dk$ then multiply by $i$ on the right and the left and write down the resulting complex structures. one of them will be the one you are thinking of and the other one will correspond to the second $SU(2)$.

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch oh, it's that simple? In principle one could have something else, no? For instance, one can consider the diagonal map $SU(2) \to SU(2)^2 \to SO(4)$, which is the same as $SU(2) \to SO(3)\to SO(4)$. I don't claim this is it, but so far I need convincing (I am checking your suggestion by hand, in any case!)

Comment: @DavidRoberts  $SU(2)\to SO(3)\to SO(4)$ is not injective, the maps I mentioned give embeddings of $SU(2)$ in $SO(4)$.

Comment: Ah, I see, the embeddings of $SU(2)$ in $SO(4)$ in your comments are implicit, not the obvious things coming from the product structure on $Spin(4)$. Sorry for misunderstanding!

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch I found some class exercises that says that the inclusion of $SU(2)$ in $SO(4)$ corresponding to forgetting complex structure induces the map $\pi_3(SU(2)) \to \pi_3(SO(4))$, $n\mapsto (0,n)$, using the coordinates inherited from $\pi_3(SO(4))\simeq \pi_3(Spin(4))\simeq \pi_3(SU(2))\times \pi_3(SU(2))$, so the *right* multiplication by a unit quaternion. ((3)(a).iv in https://www.dcrowley.net/Bonn2011EandRFinal.pdf)

Comment: @DavidRoberts  This agrees with what I said. If $v$ is a quaternion and $q$ is a unit quaternion then $(iv)q=i(vq)$ which means that the right $Sp(1)$ preserves the complex structure given by the left multiplication by $i$. This complex structure is more explicitly $i(a+bi+cj+dk)=ai-b+ck-dj$ That's exactly how the standard complex structure works on $\mathbb C^2$ identiofied with $\mathbb R^4$ : $i(x_1+iy_1,x_2+iy_2)=(ix_1-y_1,ix_2-y_2)$. This gives an explicit map (which is an isomorphism) from the right $Sp(1)$ to the standard $SU(2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to summarize various observations from the comments and put it all together.

Let $d\ge 5$ and let $f: S^4\to BSO(d)$ be a generator of $\pi_4(BSO(d))\cong \mathbb Z$.

Let $\gamma^d$ be the universal orientable $\mathbb R^d$ vector bundle over $BSO(d)$.

Then we have the following  diagram extending the one by the OP. It is easily seen to commute by naturality.

[image]

Note that as indicated on the diagram  the bottom $\alpha$ and the right $f^*$ are isomormphisms.

Observe that $f^*(p_1(\gamma^d))=p_1(f^*(\gamma^d))$. It is well known that $p_1$ of any vector bundle over $S^4$ is divisible by 2 (if we identify $H^4(\mathbb S^4)$ with $\mathbb Z$)  and in fact every even number is realized. In particular  $p_1$ of the Hopf  $\mathbb R^4$ bundle is $\pm 2$. The above is done in detail for example in [Milnor's classical paper on exotic $7$-spheres](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969983).

Since the two arrows ending in $Hom(\pi_4(\mathbb S^4),  \mathbb Z)$ are isomorphisms this implies that the image of the top row $\alpha$ is exactly $2\mathbb Z$ (we again identify $Hom(\pi_4(BSO(d)),\mathbb Z)$ with $\mathbb Z$).

Moreover this also shows that $\alpha(p_1)=\pm 2\beta(x)$ (recall that $x\in Hom(\pi_3(SO(d),\mathbb Z)$ is a generator).

Furthermore this shows that the clutching map of the stabilized Hopf bundle is exactly the generator of $\pi_3(SO(d))$ since if it wasn't then $p_1$ of the Hopf bundle would be a nontrivial multiple of $2$.

The clutching map of the Hopf bundle is just the identity map $\mathbb S^3=Sp(1)\to Sp(1)\cong SU(2)\subset SO(4)$ and therefore the generator of $\pi_3(SO(d))$ comes from the inclusion $SU(2)\to SO(4)\to SO(d)$.

This can also be seen in other ways without using Pontryagin classes. For example, recall the following well known picture of $SO(4)$.

Think of $\mathbb R^4$ as quaternions and $\mathbb S^3$ as $Sp(1)$ then consider the ineffective isometric linear  $\mathbb S^3\times \mathbb S^3$ action on $\mathbb R^4$ given by $(q_1,q_2)(v)=q_1vq_2^{-1}$. The kernel is $\mathbb Z_2=\{\pm (1,1)\}$ and we get $SO(4)=(\mathbb S^3\times \mathbb S^3)/\mathbb Z_2$. The first $\mathbb S^3$ commutes with multiplication by $i$ on the right and the second with multiplication by $i$ on the left. This identifies the two $Sp(1)$'s with two different embeddings of $SU(2)$ in $SO(4)$. The right $Sp(1)$ is easily seen to correspond to the standard embedding. The two $SU(2)$' give  generators of $\pi_3(SO(4))\cong\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$. Now look at the inclusion $SO(4)\to SO(5)$ and the induced map on $\pi_3$. From the homotopy sequence of the bundle $SO(4)\to SO(5)\to S^4$ we get that the map $\pi_3(SO(4))\to \pi_3(SO(5))\cong \mathbb Z$ is onto.

Since there is a unique irreducible real representation of $SU(2)$ of dimension 4 the two $SU(2)$'s are conjugate in $O(4)$ (but of course not in $SO(4)$). This conjugation can be made explicit by observing that $\overline{q(\bar v)}=v\bar q=vq^{-1}$. Hence quaternionic conjugation written as an element of $O(4)$ conjugates the two $SU(2)$'s.  Under the standard identification of $\mathbb R^4$ with $\mathbb H$ given by $(a,b,c,d)\mapsto a+bi+cj+dk$ the conjugating matrix is
diagonal $diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$.

The two $SU(2)$'s become conjugate in $SO(5)$ by $diag(1,-1,-1,-1, -1)$.
Hence the  $SU(2)$'s  have the same image in $\pi_3(SO(5))$ which must be the generator else $\pi_3(SO(4))\to \pi_3(SO(5))$ would not be onto.

Lastly, this could be seen using general theory by computing the Dynkin index of $SU(2)$ in $SO(5)$. Given a simple compact Lie group $G$ and its simple subgroup $H$ normalize their Killing forms $(\cdot, \cdot)_G$ and $(\cdot, \cdot)_H$ so that the longest roots have length $\sqrt 2$. Then the restriction of $(\cdot, \cdot)_G$ to the Lie algebra of $H$ is proportional to  $(\cdot, \cdot)_H$. The coefficient  is called the Dynkin index of $H$ in $G$.  It is always an integer and up to sign is equal to the coefficient in the induced map $\pi_3(H)\cong \mathbb Z\to \pi_3(G)\cong \mathbb Z$. For the proof see the book "Topology of transitive transformation groups" by Onishchik.

It is not hard to compute that the Dynkin index of $SU(2)$ in $SO(5)$ is 1 but won't do it as we have two other proofs already.

Comment: Thanks, Vitali, this has been a very interesting discussion all round! I was, coincidentally, thinking again about this stuff (the bits I commented) when Matthias asked his question, but I didn't know about how to get the image of $SU(2)$ in $SO(4)$ in homotopy, so it's nice to learn new things in the process.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you. I actually  figured that out during our discussion (never thought of this question before).  I feel there might be an even easier argument than the ones I suggested. I can see one more but I felt I should stop as there are 3 already.

Comment: It could be a different answer! I personally was thinking about the naturality squares linking the original pair of isomorphisms with the ones for $d=3$, where then we don't have to worry about anything except $SU(2)=Sp(1)$ and $SO(3)$.